# Server - client example with node js

Tags: node.js, client-server

I am starting to work with node.js and I am missing something basic in how client talks with node js server.
Here is what i am trying to do:

1. i have server.js, which i am running with
   node server.js

server.js:

```
console.log('Server-side code running');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('test');
});
// start the express web server listening on 8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('listening on 8080');
});
```

2. client.js:

```
fetch('/', {method:'GET'})
  .then(function(response){
    if (response.ok) console.log(response.status);
  });
```

3. client.js is then loaded in the html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My client page to listen node js server</h1> 
</body>
<script src="client.js"> </script>
```

In the browser log (i am running apache on that machine) i get:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

It is unclear to me, how pass something from server to the client (string is used just to simplify the application). Thanks for help.
Ivan.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I think you forgot to specify, in your `server.js` file, where express should go look for your javascript to serve them. Take a look at this [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, i have added:
app.use(express.static('/')) 
my files are in the same directory where server is running
but this doesn't change anything, i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The address you are requesting from client is incorrect. Please, try this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080', {method:'GET'})
  .then(function(response){
    if (response.ok) console.log(response.status);
  });
```

Edit: This is my server.js. I add an additonal middleware as you mentioned in the comments.

```
console.log("Server-side code running");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:8080");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("test");
});

// start the express web server listening on 8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("listening on 8080");
});
```

And this the terminal when I send a request from client.js:

```
PS C:\Users\murat\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Tutorial\test> node client
200
```

Comment: ok, thank you.
Now the following error occurs:



Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: Update:
the error above is happening in firefox, in other browser (internet explorer)  i get:
client.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ client.js:1
test-client.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Promise.then (async)  
(anonymous)

Comment: also added on the server side: 



app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

Comment: It's weird I'm not getting any error? Are you using any additional setup? If you, please edit your question and I can check that.